# visjs.org library : grouping and nesting

Tags: visualization

Using visjs is it possible to put a border around a group or nest nodes inside of another?  My goal is to show a hierarchical layout of groups of nodes.  For example I have 3 groups (0,1,2).  Each group has 3 nodes which may or may not have connections (edges).  No nodes will have connections to a node outside of their group.  I would love to enclose a group and show an edge from grp0->grp1 and so forth.   Is this possible?